# Is there a way to register hook NOT creating the module in PrestaShop?

Tags: php, module, hook, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm working on my own store, and I want to add some custom functionality. But this functionality is not something standalone, so I'd prefer to completely implemented via overriding controllers/classes and not to create a separate module for this.

But I have to use some hooks (for example - displayAdminProductsExtra to add new tab to admin product page, or actionProductAdd/actionProductUpdate to make some custom edits to DB). I know the way to use hooks from within the modules, but I cant find the way to do without creating my own module).

So the question - is there a way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: normally you can not do this. If you want to do you have to need override Hook class Exec function. Then you can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks are only meant to be used with modules.

When `Hook::exec()` is called it will first check if a module is attached to this hook and stop otherwise.

Here is the related code:

```php
// If no modules associated to hook_name or recompatible hook name, we stop the function

if (!$module_list = Hook::getHookModuleExecList($hook_name)) {
    return '';
}
```